# Why does inline-block and max-width not work together?

Tags: html, css

Just started learning CSS/HTML. I am creating a site for educational purposes.
I am also terrible at explaining things so I hope you understand.

SITE: `http://66.172.10.179/resolver/`

I am trying to make the max-width of box1 to be 300px.
I want to make a box like this: [image]

but for some reason if I remove display: inline-block; it looks like this:

[image]

If I keep the inline-block; and change max width to just width it works but then the issue is
the box wont resize depending on the screen site.

CSS:

```
.stats {
    padding: 15px;
}

.box1 {
    background-color: blue;
    width: 300px;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 10px;
}

.icon {
    font-size: 50px;
    color: white;
    display: inline;
}

.text {
    float: right;
    display: inline;
}
```

HTML:

```
    <section class="stats">
        <div class="box1">
            <div class="icon">
                <i class="fa fa-hdd-o"></i>
            </div>
            <div class="text">
                <p>123</p>
                <p>Servers</p>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: Why don't you use Twitter Bootstrap grid system? Your page will be responsive. Fixed widths for things such as top navigation are a bad idea in 2014.

Comment: is that what are you looking for http://jsfiddle.net/ZeLx9/

Comment: You're absolutely right.  You are terrible at explaining things.  So, i'm confused, because your title says "Why does inline-block and max-width not work together?" and your question is about why doesn't it work when you remove inline-block?

Comment: I'm not sure what you want to do, but you can use both `max-width` and `width` at the same time.

Comment: If I add max-width and width I dont think it will resize. @Erik that is what I am looking for but I need it to work with max-width so that is resize's

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `max-width` property doesn't imply any specific width. Instead, it limits the possible values of the `width` property.

Setting display to `inline-block` implies no specific width, but `block` (which is the default for `<div>` elements) implies 100% width.

To answer your question, `max-width` and `inline-block` do work together.

If your goal is to prevent the element from growing beyond the browser width, you want `max-width: 100%`.

Comment: How can I make it so the box can resize itself if the page is small? I use max-width on things so the maximum width is the max size it can be but allow it to go smaller.

Comment: @user3728587, What exactly do you mean "if the page is small?" Are you talking about screen or browser size or the amount of content? Setting `max-width: 100%` means don't grow any larger than the width of the parent element.

Comment: Yeah about the browser size so that it an squish in. I actually figured out how to do it thanks to your post. I added max-width to the box1 and added inline-block to both .icon and .text. Works good and I did not know inline-block had a kinda width set to it already. I am terrible at explaining things but thanks for your help and check out the site to see what I mean by the re sizing thing!