# svg and inline-block display issue on Firefox

Tags: css, firefox, svg

As suggested by @Robert Longson I'm rewriting original question.
I have 3 inline svgs with `bottom-padding` hack in containers. I want this boxes to be inline, so in css I've added `inline-block` and I want have width not exceeding some value so on the same container I added `max-width` attribute.

All is fine except for Firefox, where the big box is not displayed and two small boxes are much smaller compared to Chrome. 
Now as @Rahul suggested I used `width` instead of `max-width` and it fixed the issue. Looks like bug in Firefox with svg.

Link to code: https://jsfiddle.net/mikeNIN/2yjob68o/ and code:
HTML:

```
<div class='container_main' onclick=''>
  <div class='main' id='main-info'>
    <div id='weather-icon'>
      <div class="svg_container">
       <svg width="100%" style="padding-bottom: 64%; height: 1px; overflow: visible" viewBox="0 0 64 41" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMin slice" version="1.1"><g transform="translate(0,-1011.3622)"><rect width="63.8" height="40.8" x="0.1" y="1011.5" style="fill:#a662bd;stroke-linecap:round;stroke-width:0.2;stroke:#000"/></g></svg>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class='enh' id='enhanced-info'>
    <div class='svg_container_small'>
      <svg width="100%" style="padding-bottom: 100%; height: 1px; overflow: visible" viewBox="0 0 16 16" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMin slice" version="1.1"><g transform="translate(0,-1036.741)"><rect width="15.9" height="15.9" x="0" y="1036.8" style="fill:#35c062;stroke-linecap:round;stroke-width:0.1;stroke:#000"/></g></svg>
      <span>small1</span>
    </div>
    <div class='svg_container_small'>
      <svg width="100%" style="padding-bottom: 69%; height: 1px; overflow: visible" viewBox="0 0 16 11" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMin slice" version="1.1"><g transform="translate(0,-1041.3622)"><rect width="15.9" height="10.9" x="0" y="1041.4" style="fill:#4114bd;stroke-linecap:round;stroke-width:0.1;stroke:#000"/></g></svg>
      <span>small2</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
html { 
 -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
 -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
 -ms-box-sizing: border-box;
 box-sizing: border-box;
}
.main {
 text-align: center;
}
.container_main {
 min-height: 100vh;
 display: -webkit-box;
 display: -moz-box;
 display: -ms-flexbox;
 display: -webkit-flex;
 display: flex;
 flex-direction: column;
}
.svg_container {
 max-width: 12em;
 display: inline-block;
 vertical-align: top;
 margin-top: 10px;
 margin-bottom: 10px;
 }
 .enh {
 text-align:center;
}
 .svg_container_small {
 max-width: 6em;
 display: inline-block;
 vertical-align: top;
 margin: 10px;
 }
```

Comment: We need a [mcve] with the emphasis on minimal. We're looking for a needle in a haystack at the moment with no idea how you've constructed the haystack.

Comment: I'll try to rewrite question, although I don't know what is the source of the problem :(

Comment: source problem is your `scss` remove `@mixin` from demo. And use without @mixin

Comment: do you want set `.svg_container` and `.svg_container_small` div as side by side with center.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do this in your CSS.

```
.svg_container{
    display: block; /* No inline-block */
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}
```

[image]

**I found your issue. just follow this code.**

```
.svg_container{
    display: inline-block;
    width: 9em; /* Use width instead of max-width */
}
```

> Note:

1. `display: -moz-inline-stack;` This is the invalid property.
2. `max-width: 3em; max-width: 6em; max-width: 9em;` **Firefox** will not render `max-width` and `inline-block` in same element.

Comment: I think I tried that, I used inline-block because API can return list of values which in results give us for example two icons, one for mist and another for rain. With display:block it would display icons in column, but correct me if I'm wrong

Comment: Yes it indeed solved this issue, but I wonder why. because I found nothing about this that FF will not render `max-width` and `inline-block`. Could you point me to the source of this information? And thanks a lot!

Comment: Read it. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24718585/why-does-inline-block-and-max-width-not-work-together

Comment: The max-width property is used to set the maximum width of a given element. It prevents the used value of the width property from becoming larger than the value specified for max-width.

Comment: Ok, I must disagree on that one as in here http://stackoverflow.com/a/32216648/2700505 user showed working example. But nevertheless this was issue here, probably because of these inline svgs. I'll experiment more on this